# davfs - SSL handshake failed: SSL error: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: mount, ssl, webdav, owncloud-server

I'm trying to mount a remote WebDAV (OwnCloud) using https on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.

I run this command and it prompts me for a username and password

`sudo mount -t davfs -o uid=ne,gid=users https://example/owncloud/remote.php/webdav/ /mount/remote`

I then get the error

> /sbin/mount.davfs: Mounting failed.
>   SSL handshake failed: SSL error: sslv3 alert handshake failure

Other machines (including Android) are able to connect to the WebDAVS correctly.

How can I prevent this error?  The certificate is signed by CloudFlare, if that makes a difference - but that doesn't seem to cause a problem for any other systems accessing the OwnCloud instance.

Running `curl -v https://example.com` everything seems fine

```
* About to connect() to example.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 104.28.29.14... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server key exchange (12):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: OU=Domain Control Validated; OU=PositiveSSL Multi-Domain; CN=sni29581.cloudflaressl.com
*    start date: 2014-10-26 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2015-09-30 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: example.com matched
*    issuer: C=GB; ST=Greater Manchester; L=Salford; O=COMODO CA Limited; CN=COMODO ECC Domain Validation Secure Server CA 2
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: example.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily
< Server: cloudflare-nginx
< Date: Mon, 27 Oct 2014 11:30:08 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Set-Cookie: __cfduid=da7fc86a1e00780f7eea162120e2c4fe51414409408265; expires=Mon, 23-Dec-2019 23:50:00 GMT; path=/; domain=.example.com; HttpOnly
< Set-Cookie: DYNSRV=lin194; path=/
< CF-RAY: 17fe8f51aaa71365-LHR
< 
* Connection #0 to host example.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
* SSLv3, TLS alert, Client hello (1):
```

I've also tried `openssl s_client -host example.com -port 443` but that gives me `Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)`

```
CONNECTED(00000003)
depth=1 C = BE, O = GlobalSign nv-sa, CN = GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - G2
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:0
---
Certificate chain
 0 s:/C=US/ST=CA/L=San Francisco/O=CloudFlare, Inc./CN=ssl2000.cloudflare.com
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - G2
 1 s:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - G2
   i:/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/OU=Root CA/CN=GlobalSign Root CA
---
Server certificate
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
(truncated)
bJLtKDaYbNmULxY=
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
subject=/C=US/ST=CA/L=San Francisco/O=CloudFlare, Inc./CN=ssl2000.cloudflare.com
issuer=/C=BE/O=GlobalSign nv-sa/CN=GlobalSign Organization Validation CA - G2
---
No client certificate CA names sent
---
SSL handshake has read 3158 bytes and written 363 bytes
---
New, TLSv1/SSLv3, Cipher is ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
Server public key is 2048 bit
Secure Renegotiation IS supported
Compression: NONE
Expansion: NONE
SSL-Session:
    Protocol  : TLSv1.1
    Cipher    : ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA
    Session-ID: EAC9072E6FFBD3E7AEA20B6C4D57F229DCC887CFAB08C2D47C0A546318A794E0
    Session-ID-ctx: 
    Master-Key: 50ED2846908537665D348FCB07BB69ACEAD182F062F8235E5C7ED4958B4D446D70701E4C6876DE2DA06322BA090C46D5
    Key-Arg   : None
    PSK identity: None
    PSK identity hint: None
    SRP username: None
    TLS session ticket lifetime hint: 64800 (seconds)
    TLS session ticket:
    0000 - f1 98 d3 dc 67 02 22 1f-24 88 b7 dc 1c 1a 13 6a   ....g.".$......j
    (truncated)
    Start Time: 1414409459
    Timeout   : 300 (sec)
    Verify return code: 20 (unable to get local issuer certificate)
```

I've [tried updating to the latest libneon](https://www.tecnostore-group.com/knowledgebase/article/28/webdav-einrichten-mit-ubuntu-12-04/) but that hasn't made a difference.

### Update

Since upgrading to the latest OpenSSL, I now get a different error

> SSL handshake failed: SSL alert received: Handshake failed

As suggested elsewhere, running `openssl s_client -host example.com -port 443 -ssl3` returns:

> Verify return code: 0 (ok)

I've [compiled and installed libneon 30.1](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/basicnet/neon.html)

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --with-ssl=openssl --disable-static
```

but the error persists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right, here's what I did!

Grab [libneon 30.1](http://www.webdav.org/neon/neon-0.30.1.tar.gz) - and extract it to a directory.

Compile

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --enable-shared --with-ssl=openssl --disable-static
make
sudo make install
```

We now need to replace the old `libneon-gnutls.so` - and we want the end result to look like

```
/usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27 -> /usr/lib/libneon.so.27
/usr/lib/libneon.so -> libneon.so.27.3.1
/usr/lib/libneon.so.27 -> libneon.so.27.3.1
```

First, back up the old version.  `sudo mv /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27 /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27.old`

Then, in `/usr/lib/`

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon.so.27.3.1 libneon.so.27 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon-gnutls.so.27.3.1 libneon.so 
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libneon.so.27 libneon-gnutls.so.27
```

That made everything work!